# How to pass params into route handler pre - hapi.js

Tags: routes, hapi.js

I am using route handler pre. I want to pass permission from router so my idea is check whether that logged in user has the permission or not? When I pass parm directly it throws an error.

**Routing**

```
 server.route({ 
     method: 'GET', 
     path: '/getUser', 
     config: {
         handler: User.getUser, 
         pre: [
              { method: Activity.checkVal(1) }
         ]
     }
 });
```

**Function Call**

```
exports.checkVal = function(parm, request, reply) {
    Jwt.verify(request.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1],  Config.key.privateKey, function(err, decoded) {    
        var permissions = permissionsSet();
        if(permissions.indexOf(request.pre.val) > -1)
            return reply().continue();
        else
            reply(Boom.forbidden( "You don't have permission." ));
    });
```

}

**Error**

> Error: Invalid routeConfig options (getUser)

Is there anyway to pass paramters into route?

Comment: Can you give a little more context about what you're trying to achieve? And maybe some more code. Is `Activity.checkVal` a function that returns a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using route's "permission level" on the config object fixed my problem.

```
var checkVal = function (request, reply) {

     var permissionLevel = request.route.settings.app.permissionLevel;

     ... // decide whether to allow
};

server.route({
  config: {
      app: {
        permissionLevel: 1  // "permission level" for this route
    },
    pre: [
        checkVal   
    ]
  },
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/',
  handler: function (request, reply) {

    ... // do whatever
  }
});
```

Here is the link for reference https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/2652#event-360912937

Answer (score 0):

You can assign properties to the `request.pre` object by giving the `pre` object an `assign` property:

```
 server.route({ 
      method: 'GET', 
      path: '/getUser', 
      config: {
          handler: User.getUser, 
          pre: [
               { method: Activity.checkVal(1), assign: 'someVar' }
          ]
      }
  });
```

Then in your route handler:

```
 User.getUser = function (request, reply) {
      console.log(request.pre.someVar);
 }
```

(That's assuming your `Activity.checkVal(1)` returns a function with the usual `request, reply` signature)

**Following your edit:**

I'd suggest you want to create a closure; something like this:

```
exports.checkVal = function(parm) {

    return function preHandler(request, reply) {

        Jwt.verify(request.headers.authorization.split(' ')[parm], Config.key.privateKey, function(err, decoded) {    
            var permissions = permissionsSet();
            if(permissions.indexOf(request.pre.val) > -1)
                return reply().continue();
            else
                reply(Boom.forbidden( "You don't have permission." ));
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but i have to pass parameter to pre function.

Comment: I have already tried with assign also but it expects function (request, reply) instead of any parameter and it shows : Invalid routeConfig options

Comment: Then `Activity.checkVal(1)` needs to return a function with the correct signature. I think we need to see some more code.